# Open graph stories of action I do show up on my ticker but not on my friends' ticker

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-opengraph

I created a canvas app and defined action, object and aggregation. When I publish an action using javascript sdk by doing -

```
FB.api('/me/namespace:action?object=object_url', 'post',
            function (response) {
                if (!response || response.error) {
                    //failure
                } else {
                    //success
                }
            });
```

I get success and it shows up on my ticker and timeline but my friend is not able to see anything related to this activity neither on his ticker nor in the news feed. The visibility of activity in this app is set to friends but still nothing shows up in firends' accounts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was because I had delete 4 aggregations created automatically and created a single aggregation that I thought would only be required. I deleted this action and aggregation, created a new one from scratch and updated aggregations with action/object and it worked.